# Twitter oAuth: getting an error 215

Tags: php, oauth, twitter

I have the following code in one of my classes:

```
public function build_httpheader ($options = NULL)
{
    if (!$this->oauth_token && !$this->oauth_token_secret && !$this->http_method) {
        throw new Exception('The oauth_token, oauth_token_secret and the http method must be set');
    }
    $url = $this->base_uri;
    $url_curl = $this->base_uri;
    if ($options) {
        $this->options = $options;
        $url .= '?';
        $url_curl .= '?';
        $count = count($options);
        foreach($options as $key => $value) {
            $count = $count--;
            if ($count) {
                $url .= '&'.$key.'='.$value;
                $url_curl .= '&'.$key.'='.rawurlencode($value);
            } else {
                $url .= $key.'='.$value;
                $url_curl .= $key.'='.rawurlencode($value);
            }
        }
    }
    $this->url = $url_curl;
    /**
     * @internal Create a 32 chars unique string to
     * use as the nonce value
     */
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
    $usec = str_replace('0.', '', $usec);
    $nonce_str = utf8_encode($sec.$usec.'ABCD'.$sec);
    $oauth_nonce =  md5($nonce_str);
    /**
     * @internal Create the initial oAuth array
     */
    $oauth = array (
        'oauth_consumer_key' => $this->consumer_key,
        'oauth_nonce' => $this->$oauth_nonce,
        'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
        'oauth_token' => $this->oauth_token,
        'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
        'oauth_version' => '1.0'
    );
    /**
     * @internal generate basic info
     */
    $t_oauth = array();
    ksort($oauth);
    foreach($oauth as $key=>$value){
        $t_oauth[] = "$key=" . rawurlencode($value);
    }
    $base_info = $this->http_method."&" . rawurlencode($url) . '&' . rawurlencode(implode('&', $t_oauth));
    $composite_key = rawurlencode($this->consumer_secret) . '&' . rawurlencode($this->oauth_token_secret);
    $oauth['oauth_signature'] = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_info, $composite_key, true));

    $oauth_string = 'Authorization: OAuth ';
    $values = array();
    foreach($oauth as $key=>$value) {
        $values[] = "$key=\"" . rawurlencode($value) . "\"";
    }
    $oauth_string .= implode(', ', $values);
    $this->http_headers = array ($oauth_string, 'Expect:');
}

public function tw_curl_api_call ()
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->http_headers);
    if ($this->http_method == 'POST') {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    }
    if ( ($this->http_method != 'POST') && ($this->http_method != 'GET') ) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $this->http_method);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);

    $result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), TRUE);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return array ('result' => $result, 'info' => $info);
}
```

Another script uses this class as follows:

```
$options = array ('resources' => 'help,users,search,statuses');

$tw_wrapper->build_httpheader ($options);

$results = $tw_wrapper->tw_curl_api_call ();
```

I am however getting an error 215 (bad authentication data). Any ideas (I am aware that there are existing PHP oAuth classes and twitter wrappers, but it does not seem as if any of them has completely migrated to the 1.1 API).

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at [Codebird?](https://github.com/mynetx/codebird-php) It has support for 1.1 and works well for what I've needed. YMWV of course.

A simple example:

```
Codebird::setConsumerKey('KEY', 'SECRET');

$cb = Codebird::getInstance();
$cb->setToken('AUTH_KEY', 'AUTH_SECRET');

$result = $cb->statuses_userTimeline(array(
    'include_rts' => true,
    'screen_name' => 'hansnilsson',
));
```

Comment: Yes, I have looked at Codebird and I can't seem to get it to work. If you have an example for working with Codebird, please post

Comment: Hmmm, this works, but I tried users_lookup and that's not working. I believe this is a Twitter bug: $result = $cb->users_lookup(array('user_id'=>'12345')); gives an error 34, while $result = $cb->users_lookup(array('screen_name'=>'hansnilsson')); produces the correct profile. I posted the bug to the Twitter discussion group. This call was working a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: Having said that, I am still looking for an answer to my question

Comment: user_id should perhaps be an int? Other that that, hope you'll find a correct answer.

Comment: I suggest you read the users/lookup API docs. The user_id field is a comma separated list of up to 100 IDs.